# How to prevent Windows from presenting dialog with "Debug Error! abort() has been called"?

Tags: c++, windows, error-handling

We have some code which has been known to crash from time to time, leaving resources in an invalid state. I am writing tests which are designed to ensure that the cleanup code we have will reliably determine if the resources are invalid and, if so, reset them. As far as I can tell there is no way to simulate the state of these resources without actually crashing the program, because the destructors of classes outside of our control close them.

As such, my tests spawn a child process which acquires the resource and calls `std::abort`. This all seems to be working fine, and tests are passing on Linux and macOS. However, the following dialog keeps popping up on Windows:

[image: Error Dialog]

I can avoid this by running the tests in Release Mode, but I want to be able to debug them if something goes wrong. Because I'm spawning multiple child processes and timing is very important, the dialog actively gets in the way of debugging. The following is what I have tried. How can I get the call to abort to not result in the dialog appearing, in Debug mode?

```cpp
#include "Windows.h"
#include "errhandlingapi.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS |
               SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX |
               SEM_NOALIGNMENTFAULTEXCEPT);
  std::abort();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`std::quick_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/quick_exit) instead?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I did not know that function existed. That's exactly what I was looking for! I'll accept that as an answer, or I can post it if you're too busy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`_set_abort_behavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-abort-behavior?view=vs-2019) with parameters `_set_abort_behavior(0, _WRITE_ABORT_MESSAGE | _CALL_REPORTFAULT)` on program startup to suppress both the "abort() has been called" message (which, in debug,  includes the debug/retry/ignore buttons) and the Watson crash dump generation.  The first parameter clears both flags, and the second is a mask for which flag bits to set.

Comment: I believe you mean `_WRITE_ABORT_MSG`, not `_WRITE_ABORT_MESSAGE`, but otherwise that does exactly what I wanted! The only header required is `stdlib.h`